# Most concise way to add together 2 collections in Java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

When writing Scala spark code, if I want to add together two collections, I can simply write

```
myRdd.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

If I want to do the same in Java, however, I have to do

```
myPairRdd.reduceBykey((s1, s2) -> {
    s1.addAll(s2);
    return s1;
}
```

I was wondering if there was a more concise way of writing the Java code.

Comment: Just a note - you typically shouldn't use `.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)`

Comment: Really? I've never heard of this. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It is just quite ugly performance wise.

Comment: I mean complexity of `++` alone is bad, when performed in loop it is even worse, and GC will hit you at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a list for each key, consider the following:

```
pairRDD.groupByKey().mapValues(_.toList)
```

Comment: You should really avoid using groupByKey. Also, my values are already in the form of a collection; I was wondering if there was a more concise way of combining them.

Comment: @alexgbelov Actually `groupByKey` would be an optimal approach here (if Daniel replaced `_.toList` with `_.flatten`). Just not concise in Java.

Comment: Why? reduceByKey is generally faster. Also, again, I'm not trying to convert my values into a list; I'm trying to find a one line way of combining two lists.

Comment: `reduceByKey` is efficient if and only if function you pass there is efficient given its contract. Pretty much the same reasons as `reduceByKey` with `_ ++ _` on collections is incredibly bad idea.